# Uploading to YouTube makes all browser tabs and devices disconnect

Tags: networking, youtube, upload

Whenever I upload a video to YouTube all other browser tabs behave like there is no connection at all. It even affects my phone and other computers on the network therefor I think it has to do with my router. When the upload is done everything works normally again. I never observed this behavior with any other upload.

My router is a Fritz!Box 7390 and my uploading PC is connected through a 1000mb/s switch (wired) to the router.

Uploading through another browser does not change anything.

I understand that other sites become slow as the network resources are limited, but stopping altogether feels wrong.

speed.io measures for my internet connection: 40.894 Kbit/s down, 2.685 Kbit/s up, 29 ms ping, 2.048 con/m connects

Comment: Your upload speed isn't that rich. Uploading must be congesting all your throughput. Check how much throughput does your browser eat up when you're uploading in Task Manager->Resource Manager for example.

Comment: I cannot agree to @Nifle change of my question as it definitely affects only youtube uploads as far as my tests go.

Comment: @Ashtray : You are right, but there is a difference between slow and not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My provider provides an IPv4 and an IPv6 address and I disabled IPv6 in my own router completely which stopped all issues.

I think, it must be a faulty setup of something IPv6 and QOS related inside my router or at my provider. And it happens only with youtube because it is one of the few sites, which does IPv6 already.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem when Uploading files to [uploaded.to](http://uploaded.to). I am using a Fritzbox 6360 from a German Cable ISP.  I have a public IPv4 and IPv6 Address on my modem.  Because I don't want to disable IPv6 I found out that when throttling the upload bandwidth a bit (i did 5%) the upload worked out fine.  But this is rather a workaround than a permanent solution..